# Can one NFC tap initiate multiple actions from the same tag?

Tags: nfc

If a single user taps a single tag a single time, can the tag be encoded such that it **both** sends an SMS (or, at least, launches the SMS app) **and** launches a URL connection?

Is this the best S.E site to ask?

---

[Update] I can't rely on any particular app being installed. Can this be done with a fresh out of the box Android / iPhone?

Comment: I'm pretty sure [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) can do this.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't rely on any particular app being installed :-(

Comment: In that case I'm not sure it's possible, sorry. What's the specific use case? Maybe there's another way around this.

Comment: use case: man in the street taps a tag - his SMS app should open, with some pre-loaded text **and** a URL should be launched, so that I can count the number of interactions with the tag (irrespective of whether the SMS was sent or cancelled)

Comment: Hmmm, have you looked into just loading the webpage with a sms uri? You can specify some default text and a number to send to.

Comment: That's last ditch, but possible (+1). However, if at all possible, I want to launch two apps - SMS & bowser (the URL will got to a page where I have some PHP to store the visit in a database, then display a page) Hmmmm, maybe two tags, very close to each other? But I can't be sure that they will both register ...